# react axios request is empty in loadUserByUsername spring security

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security

When I send axios put to login, My back-end (Spring Boot) used UserDetails get empty login (""). I thought that, my variables in axios is incorrect. Even I set hardcoded data to check whether the collected data from the form is correct. Unfortunately, I'm still sending an empty string.

```
 const handleSubmit = (event) => {
const axios = require('axios').default;
event.preventDefault();
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true



axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/login',
  data: {
    'accountLogin': accountLogin,
    'passwordAccount': passwordAccount
  }
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
  console.log('Good!')
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
  console.log('error :<')
});
```

[result username in spring UserDetails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn1fn.png)

[[result in my browser]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jNI5.png)

Spring security configure:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/register", "/swagger-ui**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("http://localhost:3000")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/index", true)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true);
}
```

Comment: please update with your spring security code, you are posting using json which means you have written a custom login endpoint. If you want to use the built in logging functionality that comes with spring boot you should post it as form parameters and use standard names `username`and `password`. Also enable spring security debug logs and post them here.

Answer (score 0):

there are several faults in your code and i highly suggest you read the chapter on `formLogin` in the [spring security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html)

You have configured this:

```
.formLogin()
```

`formLogin` means that you are going to use the built in login functionality in spring security. This is a form login, meaning it takes **FORM** parameters. You are sending your login parameters as **JSON** which is completely different.

sending form data with fetch

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('username', accountLogin);
formData.append('password', accountPassword);

axios({
  url: "http://localhost:8080/login",
  method: "POST",
  data: formData
});
```

Spring security `formLogin` takes in a `username`and a `password` per default as `form` parameters. Not `json`. And it will create a default login address for you to post the data to at `http://localhost:8080/login`

```
.loginPage("http://localhost:3000")
```

Should be removed. Spring will provide a custom built in login page that will get served if you hit a protected endpoint when you are unauthorized. If you wish to serve a different endpoint, you set this here and make sure that a pake is served there. For instance:

```
.loginPage("/myCustomLogin")
```

And then it is up to you to make sure that a login page is served from here otherwise you will get a 404 from spring security.

Depending on how you are packaging your application, if you have a node server for your frontend and a spring server for the backend, then you dont need to use `loginPage` you just post form data to `/login`. If you on the otherhand server the loginpage from the spring server, you set `loginPage` to some value, build an endpoint there, package the html files in the spring server, and write code that will serve the HTML page when you hit that endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

This is a better way of sending post requests with Axios. try this, if it didn't work I guess the problem is with your back-end code.

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/login', {
    accountLogin: accountLogin,
    passwordAccount: passwordAccount
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: It's still not working, I can show you my code in spring boot, but what you want?

Comment: @snoocky sorry but I'm not any familiar with Spring.